# What type of grammatical construction is "Look at the mess you're in"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, imperative-sentences

There is the sentence such as

> "Look at the mess you're in".

What is it mean? And could you write me some more examples? So maybe I'll understand the grammatical constructions better.

Answer (score 1):

"Look at the mess you're in" is an imperative sentence: it is directing the listener to do a certain action.

http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/impersent09.htm

> In English grammar, an imperative sentence is a type of sentence that gives advice or instructions or that expresses a request or command. (Compare with sentences that make a statement, ask a question, or express an exclamation.) Also known as a directive or jussive.

Some other imperative sentences are:

- Look at that!
- Go to the store.
- Stop what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

"Look at the mess you're in." This sentence can be read in two ways.

1. It is an imperative. The person is insisting that you look at the actual physical mess. A teenager with a messy room, might need to clean up. A clerk at the store might have to mop up all the detergent he spilled.
2. It is a colloquialism. It means, figuratively look at the mess you're in -- now you have to do something. "You've put your foot in it!" It could be that you called your girlfriend by your other girlfriend's name. Now you have to fix that figurative mess or the woman you are speaking with is going to be very mad indeed. It could be that you missed the deadline for getting your tax forms in the mail. Now, you may have to pay a fine for missing the deadline.

On Edit: I think it is: 2) figurative. John dropped the paddle into the water. Mary yelled, "Look at the mess we're in! We will have to swim back to shore."